# Has the preposition "in" been omitted in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, semantic-roles, verb-pattern

While reading a book about Programming Languages, I saw the following highlighted paragraph:

> Default values, optional segments, and catchall segments all increase
> the range of URLs that a route will match. Constraints have the
> opposite effect and restrict matches. This can be useful if an
> endpoint can deal only with specific segment contents or if you want
> **to differentiate matching closely related URLs** for different
> endpoints. Constraints are applied by a colon (the : character) and a
> constraint type after a segment variable name

So I got a little confused when facing the highlighted part above and want to know whether that part is able to be rewritten as follow:

> to differentiate **in** matching closely related URLs

Otherwise, could any one explain the role of words came in the highlighted part above?(for example the word matching is an adjective and ...)

Comment: You should indicate what you already know before asking other people what they know. (Do you know that "to differentiate" is a verb, for example?) Doing so will help you to get better answers.

Comment: The (optional) preposition before a *plural* object in your context is ***between***, not ***in***. I would expect most dictionaries to give example usages showing that.

Comment: _matching_ is an adjective, part of the phrase _matching [closely related] URLs_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the original phrasing is a bit clunky. A simpler sentence with the same grammatical essentials:

- It is easy to differentiate pronouncing their names.

This could be a loose way of saying "differentiate the pronunciations of their names", or "differentiate how their names are pronounced".

The passage

> ...or if you want to differentiate matching closely related URLs for different endpoints.

might be rewritten as "or if you want to differentiate how closely related URLs for different endpoints are handled when matching them".

Comment: Thanks, I think so! I have another question, what does the word "for" act in the section '**for** different endpoints'? Are we allowed to replace it with the word "of"(I mean: URLs **of** different endpoints)?

Comment: If I understand the passage correctly: yes, "of" also works. They are URLs that belong to/are used to access different endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

"Differentiate" is a verb and this verb takes a direct object.  There are two common constructions:

> differentiate Dupont from Dupond... (direct object and "from" prepositional phrase)

> differentiate the twins  (plural direct object)

It would not be possible to replace that direct object with a PP headed by "in".

It would be possible to say

> differentiate between the twins.

Comment: In both your "twins" example and OP's cited context, we *could* optionally introduce ***between*** between ***differentiate*** and the (plural) direct object. But not ***in***.